# How to trigger React TransitionGroup and Transition to animate onLoad

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

Given the React component below which uses React Transition Group, how can I get the Transition animation to render on component load?

import React from 'react';
import { TransitionGroup, Transition } from 'react-transition-group';

```
const FeatureItem3 = class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      animate: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (           
        <TransitionGroup>
          <Transition
            in={this.state.animate}
            timeout={0}
          >
            <div>xxx</div>
          </Transition>
          <Transition
            in={this.state.animate}
            timeout={1000}
          >
            <div>yyyy</div>
          </Transition>
          <Transition
            in={this.state.animate}
            timeout={2200}
          >
            <div>zzzz</div>
          </Transition>
        </TransitionGroup>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the Transition component does not alter the behavior of the component it renders, it only tracks "enter" and "exit" states for the components. It's up to you to give meaning and effect to those states.

https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition

Example from their docs:

```
import Transition from 'react-transition-group/Transition';

const duration = 300;

const defaultStyle = {
  transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
  opacity: 0,
}

const transitionStyles = {
  entering: { opacity: 0 },
  entered:  { opacity: 1 },
};

const Fade = ({ in: inProp }) => (
  <Transition in={inProp} timeout={duration}>
    {(state) => (
      <div style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}>
        I'm a fade Transition!
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still wondering...

You will need to add **appear** attribute to the Transition/CSSTransition tag. Refer the documentation link:

http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-appear.

You can also use **key** attribute on the same tags and update it on component mount. This will achieve same result but with more control than just mounting.